# How can I shorten the argument list sent to a script, and then eval the rest of the shortened list?

Tags: bash

I've got a script that needs to do some stuff with `$1` and `$2`, and afterwards it needs to execute the rest of the arguments sent to it if they exist. Currently, I'm trying to do this:

```
  if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
    ${@:3}
    eval $@
  fi
```

But this doesn't seeem to be working. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

To clarify further: $1 is a file, $2 is a another script, and $@ should be another script followed by any arguments to that final script.

Comment: What do the arguments represent? Are they command names, or a mix of command names and arguments to those commands. Using `eval` is almost certainly the wrong way to go; can you provide a concrete example of how your script is called, and what it should do with the arguments?

Comment: Use `shift 2` prior to `eval`.

Comment: @chepner Edited in a bit of clarification to the OP. Trying the shift method suggested currently/

Comment: You are looking for `shift`. For convenience, Bash allows `shift 2` for shifting multiple parameters, but IIRC this is not portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing whether `$3` has nonzero length is not at all the same thing as testing whether it exists.  To test the number of positional parameters, use `$#`.  For example,

```
if test $# -gt 2; then
# ...
fi
```

How to "do something" with the remaining arguments depends greatly on what you actually want to do, but to avoid those parameters being subjected to (additional) word splitting, you would want to expand `$@` within double quotes.  For example,

```
# shift off the first two positional parameters
shift 2

# execute the remaining parameters as a command, with each parameter as
# one word
"$@"
```

As @chepner observes in his comment, you can skip the `shift` if you wish by using this expansion instead to get the positional parameters starting from the third:

```
"${@:3}"
```

That's a bit clearer and more concise if you know that it's always exactly the first two parameters that you'll want to skip, but `shift` can be very convenient in some cases, such as for chewing through a parameter list that may contain optional components, to avoid tracking or using variable indexes into the parameter list.

Comment: Even the `shift` isn't strictly necessary; `"${@:3}"` would skip the first two arguments, and do nothing if arguments 3 and on weren't actually set.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner; I have added that to my answer, along with some commentary on using that form vs. using `shift`.

Comment: So ${@:3} should execute arguments 3 and on if they exist? Why wasn't this happening in the segment I posted in the OP then?

Comment: @FutureShocked, I recommend expanding it within double quotes, as shown in my answer, but yes, your original code should work.  And it *does* work for me, modulo the extra word-splitting issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shift` to get rid of `$1` and `$2` after processing first 2 arguments:

```
# discard first 2 arguments
shift 2

# now handle remaining aguments if they exist
(($#)) && "$@"
```